optimal strategies in coin toss game with multiple patterns selection
In a coin toss game, two players each select a specific sequence of a certain length, and the player whose sequence appears first wins. The case where each player selects only one sequence has been extensively studied in various documents. For instance, when the sequences are of length 3, and Player A selects $\text{HHH}$ while Player B selects $\text{THH}$, it can be intuitively and mathematically confirmed that Player B has a higher chance of winning.
However, I am curious if Player B can maintain a winning strategy in situations where each player selects multiple sequences. To explore this, let's slightly modify the rules: Player A selects a set of sequences, and Player B can choose the same sequences as Player A. If an overlapping sequence appears, the game is declared a draw.
The problem is as follows: Each player selects $m$ sequences of length $n$, with Player A choosing first and Player B observing Player A's choices before making their own. Under these conditions:
What are the values of $n$ and $m$ for which Player B can ensure that their probability of winning is greater than Player A's probability of winning?
I would appreciate insights or references to similar problems in game theory or probabilistic sequence analysis.

Do you already know all the sequence matchups? Should be 64 matchups, or (I think) 12 matchups up to symmetry. Learning these for the single-sequence case, first, should help you understand the more complicated situation you're interested in

@ZubinMukerjee I already know single-sequence case. but in multiple-sequence case and "draw" rule, it seems that the single case cannot be used simply.
